# Merge [thermal-printer] into [printer]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Why do we have [thermal-printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thermal-printer)? Should we merge this in to [printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printer)?

Comment: Because programming for them is fundamentally different.  Tough tag, pretty hard to get a helpful vote when you have to explain that they are not going to be done for another month or two.

Comment: Dunno why the harsh negative vote, legit question but probably needs some research done

Comment: @OliverS. As we are in Meta and this post is an actionable request, the downvotes probably indicate disagreement with the request.

Comment: @duplode fair enough

Answer (score 2):

[As Hans Passant points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365058/merge-thermal-printer-into-printer#comment567998_365058), "programming for them is fundamentally different". One example I am aware of is [zpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zpl) -- as the tag wiki tells us, "ZPL stands for the "Zebra Programming Language" and is a proprietary programming language used to communicate to Zebra branded printers". While it is possible that tag cleanup would be appropriate for [thermal-printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thermal-printer), it doesn't seem merging it with [printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printer) would work well.